# Display old data in select tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know there are a few similar questions out there and I have already tried applying their solution but it's still not showing the old data of daysToDeliver property. I think it is because I didn't manage to use it correctly in the `echo`.

```
 <select name="daysToDeliver"
     class="form-control @error('daysToDeliver') is-invalid @enderror"required>
      <?php 
       $start_date = 1;
       $end_date   = 90;
       for( $j=$start_date; $j<=$end_date; $j++ ) {
           echo '<option value='.$j.'>'.$j.'</option>';
       }
      ?>
   </select>
```

Is there any idea to show the old data as selected option ?

Answer (score 0):

*You can use old function like this.*

```
  <select name="daysToDeliver"
     class="form-control @error('daysToDeliver') is-invalid @enderror"required>
      <?php 
       $start_date = 1;
       $end_date   = 90;
       $selected = null;
       for( $j=$start_date; $j<=$end_date; $j++ ) {
          if(old('daysToDeliver') == $j){
            $selected = ' selected';
          }
          echo '<option value='".$j.".$selected.'>'.$j.'</option>';
          $selected = null;
       }
      ?>
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it's not showing any value because the old function cannot get the last request of key. But i gave it a second parameter so it's getting the value i preset now

Comment: when you redirect you must pass the last input values like. ```return redirect()->back()->withInput();```

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Laravel support directive. So it's better to avoid using php tag.
You can try this code :

```
   <select name="daysToDeliver"
     class="form-control @error('daysToDeliver') is-invalid @enderror" required>
      @for ($i = 1; $i <= 90; $i++)
           <option value="{{$i}}" {{(old('daysToDeliver') == $i) ? 'selected': ''}} >{{$i}}</option>';
      @endfor
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it's not showing any value because the old function cannot get the last request of key. But i gave it a second parameter so it's getting the value i preset now

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using `Laravel`, notice the `@error` `Blade` directive, which should make our life easier.

As you're using `Laravel`, you can use its built-in `old` helper function which does exactly what you want.

Basically, `old` returns the value of a form element from the last request by its key (which is the `name` attribute of the form element). An example, to get the selected item from your `select` element, you'd simply do `old('daysToDeliver')` and then you!ll get the item selected by the user or `null`******* if no element was selected.

> *******: we can change that default behaviour by passing the return value we want as the second parameter of `old` function if the element
> cannot be found in the last request. So, `old('form_element_name', 5)`
> will return `5`, instead of `null`, if `form_element_name` key cannot
> be found.

To answer your question, here's a simple solution :

```
<select name="daysToDeliver" class="form-control @error('daysToDeliver') is-invalid @enderror" required>
      <?php 
       $start_date = 1;
       $end_date   = 90;
       for( $j=$start_date; $j<=$end_date; $j++ ) {
           echo '<option value="'.$j.'" '.(old('daysToDeliver') == $j ? 'selected':'').'>'.$j.'</option>';
       }
      ?>
</select>
```

Notice that part `old('daysToDeliver') == $j ? 'selected':''` which will select the item that the user has selected  when submitting the `form`.

> Anyway and for simplicity, the answer can be improved by using `Blade`
> directives instead of directly injecting `php` blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it's not showing any value because the old function cannot get the last request of key. But i gave it a second parameter so it's getting the value i preset now

Comment: Anyway, glad you found something helpful.